# Change div content based on id in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve tabbed content where it's content will change based on the id of the selected tab.

**Runthrough**:

- There are two `item`'s (two tabs)
- I'm running the `item` container through a `for loop`. so for every new tab created, a new `item` div will be generated.
- In the `for loop` I'm running `id="{{ loop.index }}" data-id="{{ loop.index }}"`. So it will iterate through each `item` and give it an id. I.e. if there's one `item`, it will have the id of 1, two `items` and they'll be two `item` divs with the ID's 1 and 2.
- Based on which `item` is clicked, I want to select the content within it and show it in `.text-container`.

For demo purposes, I've duplicated `item`, since my original code is in HUBL (HubSpot language).

```js
jQuery('.tabbed__images.item').click(function() {
  jQuery('.tabbed__images .line').css('background-color', 'rgb(193,231,255)');
  jQuery(this).find('.line').css('background-color', 'rgb(58,124,166)');
  jQuery('.tabbed__images .text-container').html(jQuery(this).find('.description').html());
  jQuery('.tabbed__images .img-container').html(jQuery(this).find('.image').html());
});
```

```css
.tabbed__images {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.tabbed__images .container {
  background-color: #f0f3f4;
}

.tabbed__images .select-container .item {
  height: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabbed__images .select-container .item .line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.4em;
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  background-color: #c1e7ff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s;
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.tabbed__images .text-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6em;
  margin-top: 5em;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="hidden-xs container container-custom tabbed__images">
  <div class="container container__narrow">

    <div class="select-container">

      <!-- original HUBL -->
      <!--{% for item in module.tab_1 %} 
      <div class="item" style="width: 25%;" id="{{ loop.index }}" data-id="{{ loop.index }}">
        <div class="text">{{ item.tab_header }}</div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="hidden description">{{ item.tabbed_text }}</div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}-->

      <div class="item" style="width: 25%;" id="{{ loop.index }}" data-id="{{ loop.index }}">
        <div class="text">Tab 1</div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="hidden description">Text of tab 1</div>
      </div>

      <div class="item" style="width: 25%;" id="{{ loop.index }}" data-id="{{ loop.index }}">
        <div class="text">Tab 2</div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="hidden description">Text of tab 2</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- show content here -->
    <p class="text-container">This text here will be replaced</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the hidden description to appear in `text-container` on tab click? I.e if I click `Tab 2`, `text-container` will read `Text of tab 2`.

Comment: Hi @Freddy why aren't you using jquery ui [jqueryui](https://jqueryui.com/), twitter bootstrap [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) or one of their plugins to achieve this?
Seems like one of those controls will suit your needs swimmingly!

Comment: you need to add space between .tabbed__images and .item -  $('.tabbed__images .item').click(function() ... after that your code should work

Comment: here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tm1xbwv8/ 
just add space and everything will work fine

Comment: @Solonka - Legend! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just change the text of the paragraph on click of the div. Find the text of it's sibling div using the function `siblings()`

```
 $('.text').click(function(){
    $('.text-container').html($(this).siblings(".hidden_description").html());
    })
```

```js
jQuery('.tabbed__images.item').click(function() {
  jQuery('.tabbed__images .line').css('background-color', 'rgb(193,231,255)');
  jQuery(this).find('.line').css('background-color', 'rgb(58,124,166)');
  jQuery('.tabbed__images .text-container').html(jQuery(this).find('.description').html());
  jQuery('.tabbed__images .img-container').html(jQuery(this).find('.image').html());
});
$('.text').click(function(){
$('.text-container').html($(this).siblings(".hidden_description").html());
})
```

```css
.tabbed__images {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.tabbed__images .container {
  background-color: #f0f3f4;
}

.tabbed__images .select-container .item {
  height: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabbed__images .select-container .item .line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.4em;
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  background-color: #c1e7ff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s;
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.tabbed__images .text-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6em;
  margin-top: 5em;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="hidden-xs container container-custom tabbed__images">
  <div class="container container__narrow">

    <div class="select-container">

      <!-- original HUBL -->
      <!--{% for item in module.tab_1 %} 
      <div class="item" style="width: 25%;" id="{{ loop.index }}" data-id="{{ loop.index }}">
        <div class="text">{{ item.tab_header }}</div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="hidden description">{{ item.tabbed_text }}</div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}-->

      <div class="item" style="width: 25%;" id="{{ loop.index }}" data-id="{{ loop.index }}">
        <div class="text">Tab 1</div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="hidden_description">Text of tab 1</div>
      </div>

      <div class="item" style="width: 25%;" id="{{ loop.index }}" data-id="{{ loop.index }}">
        <div class="text">Tab 2</div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="hidden_description">Text of tab 2</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- show content here -->
    <p class="text-container">This text here will be replaced</p>

  </div>
</div>
```